# Calculating multiple suspended statuses of a record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How do you calculate days of a log whenever a record is suspended and made active multiple times. Do I want to assign a sequential number to each time it was suspended? Or is there a better way to do this?

For instance

```
If count(suspendeddate)++ >1 set sequentialnumber to 1, 2, 3
```

DATA:

```
id logdate  status
1  1/1/2015 suspended
1  1/2/2015 active
1  1/3/2015 active
1  1/5/2015 active
1  1/5/2015 suspended
2  1/2/2015 suspended
2  1/6/2015 active
2  1/7/2015 active
```

Result

```
id  suspendeddays1 suspendeddays2
1   1              369 
2   4              0
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate suspended days, use `lead()`:

```
select d.*,
       datediff(day, logdate, next_logdate) daysOfSuspend
from (select d.*,
             lead(logdate) over (partition by id order b logdate) as next_logdate
      from data d
     ) t
where status = 'suspended';
```

This puts each suspension on a separate row, rather than in a separate column.

Comment: What if there are multiple status changes, lets say some reason the record has 2 or 3 changes in a row that the status was changed to active? Example edited.

Comment: Can't use lead as this is a compatibility issue.

Comment: @EPV . . . Each "suspended" status ends at the next  record.  This code still works.